# -JSONValue Failed

Tags: json, ios4

My code for **JSON** parsing:

```
// Store incoming data into a string    
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


// Create a dictionary from the JSON string
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
```

When I debug the code I am getting the **jsonString** but getting 0 key value pairs.
And Error as:

> -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=5 \"Unescaped control character '0x0'\" UserInfo=0x4d2e030
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unescaped control character '0x0'}",
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: id\" UserInfo=0x4d2e130 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4d2e090
>   \"Unescaped control character '0x0'\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object
>   value expected for key: id}",
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x4d2e180
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x4d2e110 \"Object value expected for key: id\",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}",
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: predictions\" UserInfo=0x4d2e250
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x4d2e210 \"Expected value while parsing array\",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: predictions}"

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON validator](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to validate your string whether that is a valid JSON.